# What does libgs10-dev relate to?

Tags: package-management, compiling

As part of an installation process I am instructed to install libgs10-dev, however I cannot find any reference to this package outside of [this installation guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=IftkzqRjbO4C&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22libgs10-dev%22) ("Hacking the Kinect", Apress, 2012).

Firstly, what is this package?

Secondly, how can I install this package (apt-get install does not seem to find it)?

Comment: Could it possibly be a typo and actually should read "libgsl0-dev" (i.e. 'L' not '1')?

Comment: Having seen the context, yes, actually, `libgsl0-dev` is more likely than `libgs-dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages called `libSOMETHING-dev` (or sometimes `ANYTHING-dev`) are development packages, which you need to compile programs from source when the program uses the [`libSOMETHING`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) library. Occasionally the package name itself contains a version number, to allow the simultaneous installation of several version.

Ubuntu doesn't have a `libgs10-dev` package, but it has [`libgs-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgs-dev). Install that. The same goes for any other package with a version number in its name — try removing or changing the number.

Answer (score 4):

This was a typo in the instructions.  It should be libgsl0-dev. They erroneously substituted a numeric one for the second letter "l"

Answer (score 0):

libgs relates to scientific computing libraries, which the RGBD demo in the book requires to run computer vision and matrix computations. Basically a linear algebra library.

I have the book as well and it seems libgs10 is a typo - it should be libgsl0 (l for lion, not 1). I simply corrected the typo and it installed beautifully.